# is there any way to measure noise in android

Tags: android, noise

how to measure noise in android,means when I run my app,there is a MIC which hear noise and send me result that noise is good or bad.

Comment: How do you define "good" and "bad" noise?

Comment: by red and green color,if color is green then it is good and if red then bad

Comment: I think you're talking about the volume of background-noise?

Comment: what is color and what is MIC noise? what is the relation?i dint get,,,,

Comment: no not now,no it is not background noise.it is like when i will stand infront of loudspeaker then it will catch the frequency of noise and then give the result

Comment: no not now i haven't try anything because i am not getting the right way

Answer (score 0):

First you go through this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) and try out some examples ..gud luck

Handling the AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY Intent

Many well-written applications that play audio automatically stop playback when an event occurs that causes the audio to become noisy (ouput through external speakers). For instance, this might happen when a user is listening to music through headphones and accidentally disconnects the headphones from the device. However, this behavior does not happen automatically. If you don't implement this feature, audio plays out of the device's external speakers, which might not be what the user wants.

Comment: I have seen this but nthing is there some other solution for it??

Comment: sorry for that.. but i thought the content in the doc "Example: Record audio and play the recorded audio would help you..."